# How can I send request using python to the tensorflow server (tensorflow-serving)?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm new tensorflow-serving.

i tried to send request(POST) to tensorflow server using python3,

but when i send reqeust, i got `<400>` , `bad request`.

but when i send curl on terminal, it's work.

```sh
curl -d '{"instances": [3]}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/hello_world:predict
```

this is my python code.

```py
import requests
import json

urls = 'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/chachacha:predict'
data = {"instances": 2858}
j_data = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.post(urls, json=j_data)
print(r)
```

error message :

```
<Response [400]>
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
data = { "instances": [values]}
payld = json.dumps(data)
ret = requests.post(url, data=payld)
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it did :)